# Check for undefined array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, jagged-arrays

I have a multidimensional array "questArray" whose index starts from 0 to 4 only.It has data in the indexes as follows

```
questArray[0][0]['q_sec']=1
questArray[1][0]['q_sec']=2
questArray[2][0]['q_sec']=3
questArray[3][0]['q_sec']=4
questArray[4][0]['q_sec']=5
```

Now, i have a for loop which iterates 40 times.Now
inside this for loop i'm using a if block to check a
certain condition with the above array as follows:

```
for(var secCnt=1;secCnt<=5;secCnt++){
  for(var noCoun=0;noCoun<40;noCoun++){
     if (secCnt == questArray[noCoun][0]['q_sec']){
       //some code here
       alert('1');
     }
  }
}
```

My problem is that, in the inner loop when 'noCoun' counter's value is greater that 4, the code does not work because there is no 'questArray' with index greater than 4. How do i check for this condition.

I have tried the following:

```
if (typeOf questArray[noCoun][0]['q_sec'] !== undefined){
         if (secCnt == questArray[noCoun][0]['q_sec']){
           //some code here
           alert('1');
         }
}

if (typeOf questArray[noCoun][0]['q_sec'] !== 'undefined'){
         if (secCnt == questArray[noCoun][0]['q_sec']){
           //some code here
           alert('1');
         }
}


if (questArray[noCoun][0]['q_sec'] !== 'null'){
         if (secCnt == questArray[noCoun][0]['q_sec']){
           //some code here
           alert('1');
         }
}

if (questArray[noCoun][0]['q_sec'] !== ''){
         if (secCnt == questArray[noCoun][0]['q_sec']){
           //some code here
           alert('1');
         }
}
```

But none of the above code works.Hope you understand my problem.Please help.Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you use array's `.length` attribute instead?

Comment: `typeOf` is incorrect. It should be `typeof` (no caps). ([MDN article on typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof))

Comment: have you tried ```if (questArray[noCoun] && secCnt == questArray[noCoun][0]['q_sec'])```

Comment: Zerkms thanks for the relpy.for testing purpose when i use alert(questArray[5][0]['q_sec'].length); no alert message is shown.But when i use alert(questArray[4][0]['q_sec'].length);,alert message is generated

Comment: mido22 as suggested by you when i use alert(typeof questArray[4][0]['q_sec']); it says 'string' but when i use alert(typeof questArray[5][0]['q_sec']); there is no alert message

Comment: _“but when i use alert(typeof questArray[5][0]['q_sec']); there is no alert message”_ – of course not, and had you checked your browser’s error console you should know why.

Comment: Why are you looping 40 times in the first place, when your array only has five entries on the main level?

Comment: CBroe thanks for your comments..I working on Online exam project.Here in each exam, there would be 5 main sections and under each section there would be 40 questions.Hence i'm looping 40 times

Comment: checking ```typeof questArray[noCoun][0]['q_sec']``` would not help because if ```questArray[noCoun]``` is ```undefined``` then, you would be trying to access a property( of a property) of undefined, and that throws an ```Error```

Answer (score 0):

this is how I would do,

```
for(var secCnt=1;secCnt<=5;secCnt++){
  for(var noCoun=0;noCoun<40;noCoun++){
     if (questArray[noCoun] && secCnt == questArray[noCoun][0]['q_sec']){
       //some code here
       console.log('1');
     }
  }
}
```

basically `questArray[noCoun]` checks if it exists, only then checks the next condition, else shorts out...

EDIT:

to be really safe, you can also do

```
if (questArray && questArray[noCoun] && questArray[noCoun][0] && secCnt == questArray[noCoun][0]['q_sec']){
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var secCnt=1;secCnt<=5;secCnt++){
  for(var noCoun=0;noCoun<40;noCoun++){
     if (noCoun < questArray.length && secCnt == questArray[noCoun][0]['q_sec']){
       //some code here
       alert('1');
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: when noCoun=0, questArray[noCoun][0]['q_sec'] will fetch value=1
when noCoun=1, questArray[noCoun][0]['q_sec'] will fetch value=2
when noCoun=2, questArray[noCoun][0]['q_sec'] will fetch value=3
when noCoun=3, questArray[noCoun][0]['q_sec'] will fetch value=4
when noCoun=4, questArray[noCoun][0]['q_sec'] will fetch value=5

But i dont understand how the following if loop will work?
if (noCoun < questArray.length && secCnt == questArray[noCoun][0]['q_sec']){
}

How does L.H.S compare to R.H.S??

Comment: if noCoun < questArray.length is false, then the right hand side will never be evaluated, as there is no need. false && true will always be false. So when noCoun goes above 4, it will stop doing the secCnt == questArray[noCoun][0]['q_sec'] check.